# What is the code to start and close tomcat 7 on terminal mac?

Tags: terminal, tomcat7

I am very new to using the terminal and using tomcat.
I had already installed tomcat yesterday and it was working, however today when I turn on my computer again, it is not working, I am assuming I need to start it up again , but I don't know how.

Can somebody explain to me or write the code to start it up please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ./startup.sh in the `bin` folder should do.

Comment: I understand the lazyness of not using google, but down voting? why ? Its a good question, he explained the situation very well. so I dont get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's the instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20120830040341/http://www.togotutor.com/tomcat/tomcat-control.php) for the `catalina.sh` shell script that controls Tomcat.

> The Tomcat control scripts resides under the bin directory inside the
>   Tomcat home (Where you have Tomcat installed). For the Unix or Unix
>   flavored operating systems the scripts with extention ".sh" needs to
>   be executed

`catalina.sh` provides a lot of options/controls, but `startup.sh` can be used to simply start it.

Comment: Thanks for the links to those instructions, where very helpful however, It is still not working. Do I need to be inside the bin folder? to run the startup.sh command?? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This works! 
Make all Tomcat's bin shell scripts executable for files under apache-tomcat-7.0.30/bin

The code is:

```
chmod a+x *.sh
```

After that Run from tomcat/bin with the script:

```
./startup.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Under some circumstances the startup scripts do not execute because the execute permission has not been set. If this is the case you can change the execute permission to the scripts by typing the following:

```
cd ../bin

chmod 750 *.sh
```

This signifies read, write, and execute permissions for the owner, read and execute permissions for the group, and no permissions for others.